# Json array looping through using javascript getting wrong output

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am pulling data from a JSON array similar to as follows:

```
"abridged_directors": [{
            "name": "Bill",
            "id": "742790769",
            "characters": ["Flint Lockwood"]
        }, {
            "name": "Anna",
            "id": "162654477",
            "characters": ["Sam Sparks"]
        }, {
            "name": "James",
            "id": "162656402",
            "characters": ["Tim Lockwood"]
        }, {
            "name": "Will",
            "id": "770670480",
            "characters": ["Chester V"]
        }, {
            "name": "Kristen",
            "id": "770792145",
            "characters": ["Barb"]
        }],
```

I am using a loop to correctly display the result.
What I am looking for is:
Bill, Ann, James, Will & Kristen

Instead I am getting:
Bill, Ann, James, Will, & Kristen

For the second last name I **do not** want a comma and the following if else statement should cover that but it doesn't seem to be working?

```
for (var i = 0;i < data.abridged_directors.length; i++){
            if(i != 0 && i == data.abridged_directors.length-1){
                // and the position of the character is greater than 0
                $(document.body).append('& ' + data.abridged_directors[i].name + '<br>');
            }
            else if(i != data.abridged_directors.length-1 || i != data.abridged_directors.length-2){
                 $(document.body).append(data.abridged_directors[i].name + ', ');
            }
            else
                $(document.body).append(data.abridged_directors[i].name + '<br>');


   }
```

I have been looking at this for a good while now and making changes but nothing seems to work. It is possibly something small I'm not seeing so sorry if that turns out to be the case!

Answer (score 1):

If you are supporting only IE9+, then you can use a map to do this. The key thing here is a separation of duties. It makes it easier to understand. If you need IE9- support, then you can do this with a for loop. See ezekielDFM's solution.

[editted to include ezekielDFM regex command - much more cleaner solution]

### Pseudo Code:

1. Build your data up first (map command)
2. Format your data (join command)
3. Fix formatting (replace command)

### Javascript

```
var string_directors = data.abridged_directors
  .map(function(director) {
     return director.name; 
  })
  .join(', ')
  .replace(/(.*),(.*)$/, '$1 & $2');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to offer a little cleaner method (imho). Instead of looping through and appending, try joining an array of the names and just replacing the last comma. See code:

```
var names = [];

for (var i = 0;i < data.abridged_directors.length; i++)
{
     names.push(data.abridged_directors[i].name);
}

$(document.body).append(names.join(', ').replace(/(.*),(.*)$/, "$1 & $2"));
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zYdH9/

Comment: Well done with the regex. I'm trying to avoid conditions and loops as much as possible in my coding these days. Your regex solution at the end is elegant.

Answer (score 0):

The `||` in the `else if` should be `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

i know you get the answer, but i spend some time with solution...kkk
Hope Help someone:

```
$(json).each(function(i){  
    $("#result").append(this.name);
    if(j-2 == i)
        $("#result").append(" & ");
    else{
        if(!(j-1 == i))
        $("#result").append(", ");}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z5L4E/